# confusion on a definition of Genus

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I was reading that the genus of a 1-holed Torus, $T$,  is 1. But then I read another definition that for an object which is closed and symmetric about the origin its genus can be decided by the smallest value $n$ such that there exists an odd, continuous function between the object and $\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}$. As per this the genus has to be $3$ because if I choose a map say the identity function which is odd continuous then the genus has to be $3$. I am failing may to be to find a odd, continuous map between $T$ and $\mathbb{R^k}\setminus\{0\}$ for $k=1,2$. Can someone clear this?. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

These are two totally different and (as far as I know) unrelated notions of "genus".  It's just the same word, used with two different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I expected so. It is really a misuse of term.

Comment: @Alexander I don't think it's really a misuse: duplicate terms are bound to come up in mathematics. For example consider how commonly adjectives such as "normal" and "regular" are used. If the contexts are sufficiently different, there is usually little confusion

Comment: Yes true. Thanks.